# SQL between with started time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some tips for my SQL problem.

When I search with timestamps like:

```
Select `guestname` 
from `Tablename` 
where `coming` between '2019-03-03 6:00' and '2019-03-03 10:00'
```

I find the guest which enter my room between 6 and 10.

But how I can find the person who arrived at 5:45 and left at 11:33?

In best case, I ignore the 15 minutes, but get the information of the Name and how long he stayed between 6 and 10.. -->(get 4 hours and the name)

When I search between the next timearea between 10 and 14ten, I will get 1:33 hour and the name of the person.

Is this possible?

Edit: Example Data

```
name    coming                     leave
Peter   2019-03-02 05:43:33        2019-03-02 09:43:33
John    2019-03-02 09:43:33        2019-03-02 11:43:55
Eva     2019-03-02 11:43:55        2019-03-02 14:23:16
Maike   2019-03-02 14:23:16        2019-03-02 22:02:16
Sarah   2019-03-02 22:02:16        2019-03-03 06:22:11
```

What i wish:

Sarah was here from 22:02:16 to 06:00:00 for 7:57:44. When i search for the 2019-03-03 Sarah was there for 00:22:11.

In this case i use mysql workbench

Comment: Two intervals `[a1, a2)` and `[b1, b2)` intersect when `b1 < a2 and b2 > a1`.

Comment: I edit it, mysql

Comment: "What I wish", it is not clear what you mean here. What exactly are you searching for and is it one or two queries and what is the expected output? I can not for instance understand what you mean when you say that Sara was there for 22 minutes roughly on the 3rd? I get it that the previous interval was from 22:02 to 06:00 but what exactly is the query?

Comment: i will try it in pseudo code: Who was there between 2019-03-02 22:00 and 2019-03-03 6:00 and how long she stays? Answer: sarah - 8 hours. If she was there to 06:22, and i ask: Who was there between 2019-03-03 06:00 and 2019-03-03 22:00 and how long she stays? Answer: sarah - 22minutes, and then other persons.